Normal stress induced in a rod if one end is free to move

Consider a cylindrical rod of uniform mass density, having a cross sectional diameter $d$. One end is free to move, and other end is subjected to a force $F$ along the longitudinal axis of the cylinder. Then what will be the stress induced in that rod?

My answer is zero.
And the reason is, stress is the force that is induced within the body per unit area, in response to the force that you have applied. Given by:
$$σ = \frac{F}{A} $$
(Where $F$ is the force that you have applied, $A$ is the area of cross section, $σ$ is the stress induced, force perpendicular to the area, so no vector notation). When one end is free to move then the force acting on that side is zero, it's looking very vague to say it. Not sure how to say it. But the formula that have been derived for calculating stress, is for the objects that have net force zero. And even if the net force is not zero you can get the stress only due to the force which is lesser in magnitude (assume forces acting opposite to each other).
Counter for my own approach:
If force is acting only from one side of the object, then stress can be induced due to acceleration of the object. Consider a mud ball in my hand and I want to throw it in a horizontal direction. Now, the weight of the ball is acting perpendicular to the direction of the force I am going to apply. So that weight is not going oppose my applied force. And there is a threshold limit of the force that a mud ball can bear say $'K'$ (obviously from opposite sides) without getting deformed.
I threw the ball with some minimum force in order to deform it.

Will this applied force be the same as $K$?

If it is same then the intuition for answer zero of the rod is wrong. Meaning that there is something that is opposing my applied force and is equal in magnitude as my applied force but the mud ball is free to move from the other end. Where the force come from? Is it the inertia or the mass of the ball. But Force , Mass and Inertia are 3 distinct quantities having different dimensional formulae. How can inertia and mass oppose force (I think I am very wrong to say this). Someone please correct me.

Rather than trying to use your intuition, solve the problem drawing free body diagrams of a small piece of the rod at each end. Apply Newton’s second and third laws given that each piece has the same acceleration as the whole rod. See the figures below.
In the top figure a differential amount of mass $dm$ is cut off at the left end of the rod (where the external force is applied).  There are two forces acting on it, the applied force $F$ and the force $F'$ that the section to the right of the cut applies to the differential mass, which is equal and opposite to the force the differential mass applies to the section to the right, per Newton's third law.
Since all sections of the rod have the same acceleration of $a=F/M$, that means the net force acting on the differential element on the left end divided by the differential mass equals that acceleration, or
$$a=\frac{F}{M}=\frac{F_{net}}{dm}=\frac{(F_-F')}{dm}$$
Solving for $F'$
$$F'=F-F\frac{dm}{M}$$
As $$\frac{dm}{M}\rightarrow 0$$
$$F'=F$$
so that the differential mass is being subjected to a compressive force approaching the applied force and compressive stress approaching $F/A$.
Similarly, looking at the differential mass on the right, it is subjected to the force $F''$ applied by the section to the left, which is equal and opposite to the force the differential mass exerts on the section to the left, with no force applied to the right of the differential mass.
So applying Newton's second law to the differential element we get
$$a=\frac{F}{M}=\frac{F_{net}}{dm}=\frac{F''}{dm}$$
Solving for $F''$
$$F''=adm\rightarrow 0$$
so that the differential mass is being subjected to a compressive force approaching zero and therefore a compressive stress approaching zero.
Bottom line: The compressive stress varies linearly along the rod being a maximum of $F/A$ at the end subjected to the applied force and zero at the end where the applied force $F''$ approaches zero.
Hope this helps.

